# Calculate routes via GET - Polyline incorrect

Tags: rest, routes, here-api, polyline

Iam testing routing API(https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html) and all seems to be working as expect except polyline.

Here I share my service invocation
`curl --location --request GET 'https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&origin=3.4844257,-76.5256287&destination=3.478483,-76.517984&routingMode=fast&return=elevation,polyline,actions,instructions,summary&apiKey=1234'`

As part of response we have the next field:

"polyline": "B2Fkt10Grm4-xE8yTU4mBnBnG8pBAzP0tBAjD4IA_E8LAvMokBT3IkXTzF8QTnG8QTvMsiBTrJjDA3_BjXoB_sB_OAriB3NAzKjDAnLsTAnLkhBnBzKsdA_J8fTnLkcT3DwHAvC8GArJoQAnL8QA7LsTA7V0jBT_M8UA",

As you know the polyline field is encoded.
According to documentation I proceeded to decoded it with a library/code suggested from:

https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline/tree/master/java

The result of decode the field in not correct. The list of points (Lat,Long,Elevation) returned are not matched with the correct location. In the example, the coordinates are from Colombia and the results, after decodification, returns a list of points in a middle of the Atlanthic ocean.

Further, in order to discard library issues I was checking decoding de polyline with other decoder as:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility
- https://open-polyline-decoder.60devs.com/

And the result is the same.

So, seems to be the problems is HereAPI side(API routing v8)

Any ideas? Maybe I am invoking the API in the incorrect way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decoder on https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline/tree/master/java works correct, see please code with your encoded string:

```
private void testSOLatLngDecoding() {
        List<LatLngZ> computed = decode("B2Fkt10Grm4-xE8yTU4mBnBnG8pBAzP0tBAjD4IA_E8LAvMokBT3IkXTzF8QTnG8QTvMsiBTrJjDA3_BjXoB_sB_OAriB3NAzKjDAnLsTAnLkhBnBzKsdA_J8fTnLkcT3DwHAvC8GArJoQAnL8QA7LsTA7V0jBT_M8UA");
        List<String> seqCrds = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < computed.size(); ++i) {
            LatLngZ c = computed.get(i);
            List<String> crds = new ArrayList<>();
            crds.add(String.valueOf(c.lat));
            crds.add(String.valueOf(c.lng));
            crds.add(String.valueOf(c.z));
            seqCrds.add(String.join(",", crds));
            //assertEquals(computed.get(i), pairs.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(String.join(",", seqCrds));
    }
```

We have a javascript tool "Encode/Decode to/from Flexible polyline" on https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3.1/enc_dec_flexible_polyline

see please result:

[image]

Please double check code on your side.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing your API key from the get request you posted in your question.

Using the polyline that you provided gets decoded into the following, which is in Columbia. As a result, I think you need to check the decoder you are using and/or what is being fed into it.

| Index | Lat | Lon | Elev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3.48437 | -76.52567 | 1003 |
| 1 | 3.48438 | -76.52505 | 1001 |
| 2 | 3.48428 | -76.52438 | 1001 |
| 3 | 3.48403 | -76.52365 | 1001 |
| 4 | 3.48398 | -76.52351 | 1001 |
| 5 | 3.4839 | -76.52332 | 1001 |
| 6 | 3.4837 | -76.52274 | 1000 |
| 7 | 3.48356 | -76.52237 | 999 |
| 8 | 3.48347 | -76.5221 | 998 |
| 9 | 3.48337 | -76.52183 | 997 |
| 10 | 3.48317 | -76.52128 | 996 |
| 11 | 3.48302 | -76.52133 | 996 |
| 12 | 3.482 | -76.5217 | 998 |
| 13 | 3.48128 | -76.52194 | 998 |
| 14 | 3.48073 | -76.52216 | 998 |
| 15 | 3.48056 | -76.52221 | 998 |
| 16 | 3.48038 | -76.5219 | 998 |
| 17 | 3.4802 | -76.52137 | 996 |
| 18 | 3.48003 | -76.5209 | 996 |
| 19 | 3.47987 | -76.52039 | 995 |
| 20 | 3.47969 | -76.51994 | 994 |
| 21 | 3.47963 | -76.51982 | 994 |
| 22 | 3.47959 | -76.51971 | 994 |
| 23 | 3.47944 | -76.51945 | 994 |
| 24 | 3.47926 | -76.51918 | 994 |
| 25 | 3.47907 | -76.51887 | 994 |
| 26 | 3.47872 | -76.5183 | 993 |
| 27 | 3.478512 | -76.517966 | 993 |